# How to texture match this 1987 drywall ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

Home was built in Houston metro area in 1987. I replaced drywall in ceiling and haven't seen any examples of this specific ceiling texture. Other homes in the neighborhood also have it. I need to replicate this for an 8'x6' repair so I'm asking the pros if anyone knows how this was achieved. It looks like a 9" brush with cut-outs was used with joint compound and then applied in multiple triangular patterns. Is there a specific name for this texture pattern and more importantly, what was used to create it?

[image: my ceiling texture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a "bagged" finish.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fPRLo_7OFA

just applied in a pattern instead of over the whole surface.

Comment: I put a bag over it and attached three rubberbands (two outsides and middle) to secure it around the roller. I then put it in all-purpose joint compound/primer mix and "blopped" it on in the pattern of the ceiling (triangles). It turned out I did it too heavy and also the pattern didn't match because it was too dense as opposed to leaving just straight-lined stipples in trianglular patterns. I've Google'd the heck out of this and all I find are the basics to stomp/stipple/slap/knockdown/popcorn, etc. I'll admit that my pattern is ugly so I'm glad it's gone out of style but it's hard to match.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try the side of a loofah that's had some strips cut randomly out of it. I used the end of one for a 3-circle pattern that was similar back in the day.