# 1980s Houston area ceiling mud texture repair replicate?

Tags: ceiling, mudding

I've asked on here and thought I had a solution but it wasn't a good match and I had to redo and start over. I now have a smooth ceiling again. I've tried so many times to replicate this pattern but can't. I've tried using a plastic bag, roller, paintbrush, etc. Nothing has worked. The house was built in 1987 in Houston, TX area. Any ideas how to replicate this pattern? It looks like stipple brush but isn't fully filled in and has a triangular pattern to it. All hints and tips are appreciated! (this is an old picture, I've since repaired the "proud" drywall seen here and now have it flat, taped, mudded 4x, and primed!

[image]

Comment: looks like lines were squeezed onto a trowel like toothpaste then dabbed.

Comment: While this may actually work, it certainly isn't efficient. I can't tell if this is a joke or not lol. It is frustrating to try and match. I've been trying on a scrap piece but still can't match it. I may have to just try this toothpaste method even if it takes me a couple hours.

Comment: You should have unaccepted the answer on the [original post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/234593/how-to-texture-match-this-1987-drywall-ceiling) and updated it rather than creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the "textured" areas could have been made by a rectangular trowel. I seen the video in the other post, and the mud is applied the same way and smoothed out. Using a flat trowel used in some drywall work, mostly in concrete work, randomly press it here and there. Thick of the mud applied will affect how the peaks form. Thicker mud, bigger peaks, thinner mud smaller peaks.

This still may only get you close, I don't know how to explain the "linear" lines of peaks. This technique, like the bagging will still yield a random pattern, not in lines, so to speak. Then again, maybe it is just the one spot in the picture I am focusing on.

Comment: I'm not sure how a trowel could make that. I start with a dry and primed ceiling then add mud/water/primer mix for the texturing. If I used a trowel to get the lines, wouldn't it just blotch everywhere upon pressing on it. I kind of like @dandavis remark of creating lines and then lightly pressing on them with a trowel.

Comment: The idea I had was to skim the ceiling and press the trowel onto the surface and pull it straight off. There would need to be some experimenting done to figure how thick to skim the ceiling. But perhaps the randomness of thickness is how the peaks are randomized too.

Comment: I can definitely see the rectangular shape of the trowel in the patterns (or maybe a sponge).  The valleys are very smooth, so it looks smoothed first then tapped the pattern on after.

Answer (score 0):

I have had 3 houses in the Houston area. The textures are not standard except each contractor seems to have his own technique. The paint sub-contractor on the house I had built used the same pad for years. When it was time to use it, it took a few minutes to remember who had the pad from last job. So you will likely need to experiment to see what looks similar.